# PyTorch RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, reinforcement-learning

I am attempting to implement the Proximal Policy Optimization (PPO) algorithm using PyTorch. My implementation is based on my understanding of how the PPO algorithm works. At a high level, the process of my implementation looks something like this:

1. First, we need to initialize the Policy Network with random parameters.
2. Then, at each time step of the current episode, we need to compute the advantage function. This involves  computing the Value functions *V(s)* and *Q(s,a)* in order to get *A(s,a) = V(s) - Q(s,a)*. In my implementation, each value function is a function approximator that optimizes both of them at each time step using a simple gradient descent approach.
3. Additionally, at each time step of the episode, I compute the clipped surrogate values at the current step.
4. At the end of the episode, I calculate the expected value of all the clipped surrogate values in order to compute the SGA (Stochastic Gradient Ascent) for optimizing the Policy Network parameters.

My Value functions and Policy Network are implemented as classes. The Value functions classes each contain PyTorch initialization and forward pass methods, as well as MSE loss and SGD methods. The Policy Network class includes initialization and forward pass methods, along with the clipped surrogate value method for computation at each time step, and lastly the SGA method. You can find the full code at https://github.com/BernardoOlisan/PPO-Clip/blob/main/ppo.py

Everything is working, but when I try to compute SGA for the policy network at the end of the episode, this **error shows up**:

```
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward()  or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
```

Some people suggested that the issue might be due to my use of `loss.backward()` in each class (value functions and policy network), and advised me to resolve it by setting `retain_graph=True` in each `loss.backward()` instance. However, this solution is not effective.

I am unsure what is causing the error in my code. Why is the Policy Network SGA throwing this error? How can I fix it? Am I making a mistake?

Here is my policy rollouts:

```
    def rollouts(self, policy, state_value_function, action_value_function):
        old_policy = copy.deepcopy(policy)

        for episode in range(self.EPISODES):
            print(f"###################################### EPISODE [{episode}] ######################################")

            (initial_state, _) = self.env.reset()
            self.env.render()
            state = initial_state
            clipped_surrogated_values = []

            for step in range(self.EPISODE_STEPS):
                print(f"---------------------- STEP [{step}] ----------------------")

                policy_output = policy.forwardPropagation(torch.from_numpy(state))
                old_policy_output = old_policy.forwardPropagation(torch.from_numpy(state))
                action = torch.distributions.Categorical(policy_output).sample().item()
                old_action = torch.distributions.Categorical(old_policy_output).sample().item()

                state, reward, terminated, truncated, info = self.env.step(action)

                target_value = torch.tensor([reward], dtype=torch.float32)

                predicted_state_value = state_value_function.forwardPropagation(torch.from_numpy(state))
                loss_state_value = state_value_function.MSE(predicted_state_value, target_value)
                state_value_function.SGD(loss_state_value, VALUE_LEARNING_RATE)

                predicted_action_value = action_value_function.forwardPropagation(torch.from_numpy(state), torch.tensor([action], dtype=torch.float32))
                loss_action_value = action_value_function.MSE(predicted_action_value, target_value)
                action_value_function.SGD(loss_action_value, VALUE_LEARNING_RATE)

                advantage = predicted_state_value - predicted_action_value
                ratio = torch.tensor((action + 1e-6) / (old_action + 1e-6), dtype=torch.float32)
                clipped_surrogate_objective = policy.clippedSurrogateObjective(ratio, advantage)
                clipped_surrogated_values.append(clipped_surrogate_objective)

                old_policy = copy.deepcopy(policy)

                # Policy Network Rollout
                print("Policy Network (π) Rollout:")
                print(f"Policy NN output: {policy_output}")
                print(f"Old Policy NN output: {old_policy_output}")
                print(f"Selected action: {action}")
                print(f"Reward received: {reward}\n")

                # State Value Function (V(s))
                print("State Value Function (V(s)):")
                print(f"Predicted Value: {predicted_state_value}")
                print(f"Loss (V(s)): {loss_state_value}\n")

                # Action Value Function (Q(s, a))
                print("Action Value Function (Q(s, a)):")
                print(f"Predicted Value: {predicted_action_value}")
                print(f"Loss (Q(s, a)): {loss_action_value}\n")

                # Clipped Surrogate Objective at t (J(θ_t))
                print("Clipped Surrogate Objective at t (J(θ_t)):")
                print(f"Ratio: {ratio}")
                print(f"Advantage: {advantage}")
                print(f"Result: {clipped_surrogate_objective}\n")

                if terminated:
                    time.sleep(1)
                    break
                time.sleep(0.1)

            expected_surrogate_objective = sum(clipped_surrogated_values)
            # Here is where the error shows up
            policy.SGA(expected_surrogate_objective, NN_LEARNING_RATE) 

            print(f"\nEPISODE DETAILS:")
            print(f"Expected Surrogate Objective: {expected_surrogate_objective}")

        self.env.close()
```

Policy Network class is this one:

```
class PolicyNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_dim, hidden_dim, output_dim):
        super(PolicyNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_dim, hidden_dim)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(hidden_dim, output_dim)

    def forwardPropagation(self, X):
        Y = torch.relu(self.fc1(X))
        Z = self.fc2(Y)
        z_hat = F.softmax(Z, dim=-1)
        return z_hat
    
    def clippedSurrogateObjective(self, ratio, advantage):
        first_value = ratio * advantage
        second_value = torch.clamp(ratio, 1 - EPSILON, 1 + EPSILON) * advantage
        return torch.min(first_value, second_value)

    def SGA(self, expected_surrogate_objective, learning_rate):
        ''' Error in here...
            RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after 
            they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() 
            or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if 
            you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.
        '''
        optimizer = optim.Adam(self.parameters(), lr=learning_rate)
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        loss = -expected_surrogate_objective
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
```

The complete code can be found at https://github.com/BernardoOlisan/PPO-Clip/blob/main/ppo.py. It's not a very large code.

Thank you in advance.